# Populate Array with a set of Strings from a for-in loop for Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, for-in-loop

I am kinda stumped on figuring this out. I want to populate an array with the string values that comes from a for-in loop.

Here's an example.

```
 let names = ["Anna", "Alex", "Brian", "Jack"]

 for x in names {
     println(x)
 }
```

The current x value would generate 4 string values (Anna, Alex, Brian, Jack).

However I need some advice in going about getting these four values back into an array. Thank you in advance.

Comment: `names` is already an array of the 4 strings you want... Or perhaps I misunderstand the question?

Comment: sorry for being unclear. What i meant was if i wanted to make a new array, let's say namearray2 that consisted of these four names. How would i go about it by using the the values that are generated by the for-in statement?

Comment: the easiest way would be without a for loop: `let newNames = names`

Comment: alternatively, if you want to perform some transformation on the strings, you need `map` i.e. `let uppercaseNames = names.map { $0.uppercaseString }` creates a new array containing `["ANNA", "ALEX", "BRIAN", "JACK"]`

Answer (score 2):

Whatever is on the right side of a `for - in` expression must be a `SequenceType`. `Array`, as it happens, can be initialised with any `SequenceType`. So if you're just doing something like this:

```
var newArray: [String] = []
for value in exoticSequence {
  newArray.append(value)
}
```

The same thing can be accomplished (faster), by doing this:

```
let newArray = Array(exoticSequence)
```

And it doesn't matter what type `exoticSequence` is: if the `for-in` loop worked, `Array()` will work.

However, if you're applying some kind of transformation to your `exoticSequence`, or you need some kind of side effect, `.map()` might be the way to go. `.map()` over *any* `SequenceType` can return an array. Again, this is faster, and more clear:

```
let exoticSequence = [1, 2, 3]

let newArray = exoticSequence.map {
  value -> Int in
  // You can put whatever would have been in your for-in loop here
  print(value)
  // In a way, the return statement will replace the append function
  let whatYouWouldHaveAppended = value * 2
  return whatYouWouldHaveAppended
}

newArray // [2, 4, 6]
```

And it's equivalent to:

```
let exoticSequence = [1, 2, 3]

var newArray: [Int] = []
for value in exoticSequence {
  print(value)
  let whatYouWouldHaveAppended = value * 2
  newArray.append(whatYouWouldHaveAppended)
}

newArray // [2, 4, 6]
```